# Javascript, Firefox replacing entire document without document.write

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have this method, which works fine, except in Firefox:

```
function write(template) {
    document.open("text/html", "replace");
    document.write(template);
    document.close();
}

write("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>MyPage</title></head><body>111</body><html>");
```

In firefox the entire page can no longer be refreshed and when you update the hash in the address field it forces a complete refresh of the page.

This doesn't happen in chrome.

Is there a different way to update entire document that makes Firefox play along?

Thanks!

**-----------EDIT----------**

I noticed there is a **document.childNodes[0].remove()** method to call which will remove the old document, but I am unable to add a new document node to that array.

```
var node = document.createElement("html");
node.innerHTML = "<body>1111</body>";
document.childNodes[0].remove();
document.childNodes[0] = node;
```

Does not seem to be working. Any hints?

**-----------EDIT 2 ----------**

```
function write(template) {
    var node = document.createElement("html");
    node.innerHTML = template;

    var head = node.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var body = node.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    if ( head ) {
        document.documentElement.replaceChild(
            head,
            document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
        );
    }

    if ( body ) {
        document.documentElement.replaceChild(
            body,
            document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
        );
    }

}
```

This successfully does replace the dom, unfortunately, unlike write it doesn't revaluate the style or script tags, making it useless :(

**------- EDIT 3 -------**

Yields the same as EDIT 2 making it also useless:

```
function write(template) {
    var node = document.createElement("html");
    node.innerHTML = template;

    document.replaceChild(node, document.childNodes[0]);

}
```

**----- EDIT 4 -----**

See my answer below

Comment: `document.open()` does not have parameters : http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170

Comment: More importantly, the browser itself does not seem to support parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open

Comment: It behaves differently actually without the second parameter at least. If replace is not present, after the write you will be able to go back in history using the back button on the browser. If it is, then you can't.

Comment: _“but I am unable to add a new document node to that array. `document.childNodes[0] = node`”_ – this does not work, because NodeLists (that’s what that is, it’s _not_ an ordinary array) are read-only. If you want to add a node to a DOM element, you need to use the methods designed for this, like `insertBefore`, `appendChild` or `replaceChild`. But those are not available on the document object I think, only on actual DOM nodes.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor FYI: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I noticed that. insertBefore was tested earlier and doesn't exists on document. replaceChild do exists but yields the same as the edit 2 above

Comment: @MoJS You trusted w3schools ?! oops. Read http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It is still supported in my browsers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, jQuery is able to revaluate scripts when html() is used correctly, here is the write method :

```
function write(template) {
    var node       = document.createElement("html");
    node.innerHTML = template;

    var head = node.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var body  = node.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    if ( head ) {
        jQuery("head").html(head.innerHTML);
    }

    if ( body ) {
        jQuery("body").html(body.innerHTML);
    }

}

write("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>MyPage</title></head><body>111</body><html>");
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make use of the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function of jQuery. (or [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) if you prefer to make use of pure Javascript)

If the document DOM has already been loaded you shouldn't be using `document.write`.

Comment: The question title is `Firefox replacing entire document without document.write`

Comment: I agree, the html() function doesn't do what I am after. I want to replace the entire document, including the head, title and what not. It works fine in other browsers ( haven't tested IE )

Comment: @MojJS, no, but you can use it with `html` or `body`:  `$('html').html('aaaa');` or `$('body').html('aaaa');`.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the DOM, you can manually revalute `script`s and `style`s, by creating new elements:

```
function write(template) {
  var node = document.createElement("html");
  node.innerHTML = template;

  var head = node.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var body = node.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  if ( head ) {
      document.documentElement.replaceChild(
        head,
          document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
      );
  }

  if ( body ) {
      document.documentElement.replaceChild(
        body,
         document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
    );
  }


var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
styles = document.getElementsByTagName("style");

var or_scripts_length = scripts.length,
or_styles_length = styles.length;

//reproduce scripts
for(var i=0; i<or_scripts_length; i++){
   new_script = document.createElement("script");
   new_script.setAttribute("src", scripts[i].src);
   document.head.appendChild(new_script);
  if(i == or_scripts_length)
     break; //in order to avoid revaluating new created scripts which results to an infinite loop
 }

 //do the same for styles
}
```